# Filtering By Values in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet containing columns for Timestamp, Company, UserID. Each row in the spreadsheet indicates that a given user from a particular company has performed an action.

I've created a Pivot Table, the "Add this data to the Data Model" option, to see which companies have the most actions by its users and how many users from each company are performing actions:

In Power Pivot

- **Company** and **User** are the Rows
- **Values** is in the Columns
- **Count of Actions** and **Distinct Users** are the Values

[image: pivot table sample]

I'd like to be able to filter out users who have only performed 1 action, allowing me to see which users are repeat action performers.

I've attempted to filter the Row Labels, but only appears to filter Companies whose **Count of Actions** is 1. How can I filter by the Users' Count of Actions *values*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like a filter can be applied to the fields in the Pivot Table Tools:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select cell D2 (i.e. the column immidiately to the right of your pivot table and first row below the headings) and click on Data -> Filter.  Auto-Filter indicators will appear in each of the column headings.

Comment: This also appears to only filter the total of the Company (e.g. a Company has only 1 User that has performed 1 Action).